# Is it possible to get the points of bitmap as path?

Tags: android, bitmap, shapes, touch-event

suppose my bitmap is like [image: balloon]
This image is actually in square transparent. I want to get the only viewable points as array so I can bound it and handle touch event on `canvas`. Right now it is square so when I touch at the corner of the image it still detect touch event on image. i don't want to do like this. Only if user clicked on viewable part then only action would be taken otherwise not.

For temporary I have used radius of image from center point it works fine but accurate, also if this image triangle part length is long then if it remain in square format user fill/get event on image outside.

I have used `canvas` to draw bitmap. Is there any other way or easy way to do this thing and handle event.

I have seen many games in that they used like custom shapes and touch event fire only on display part of object, how could i achieve this things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at coordinates:
[Android Canvas Coordinate System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931278/android-canvas-coordinate-system)
and
http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/SpriteMethodTest/src/com/android/spritemethodtest/CanvasSprite.java?r=150
Which goes into sprite:
http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-paint-animate-loop-and-remove-a-sprite/

This may help too:
http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-vi,209.html

Some of that should be helpful.

Comment: Hi, i get the points of bitmap and drawn on canvas, now my question is how to bound that points as an one object and when user touched on within the region of points the object is moved according to that.Is there anyway to bounds points ?

Comment: It's best to ask/start a new question to get the best help. Post your progress and problem you're now facing in a new post. Thanks.

Comment: this is what my question : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699761/how-to-bound-set-of-points-custom-shape-and-touch-event-on-it-android"