# how to bound set of points (custom shape) and touch event on it android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

i am able to get my bitmap set of points (as an array) using [this link](http://brownandroidattack.blogspot.com/2010/03/image-transparency-aka-absurd.html) 
now my question is how can i bound these points as shape/region. Means when user touched on area of my bounded points, i want to move objects(shape) according to that. Above link return points of colored bitmap (it remove transparent part), only colored part points are return as an array. 
This is what my code :

1) CustomSahpe.java

```
public class CustomShape {
private final Context context;

Bitmap bitmap;
int width, height;
int[] pixels;
private final ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
public CustomShape(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    // super(context);
    this.context = context;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_menu_balloon);
    width = bitmap.getWidth();
    height = bitmap.getHeight();
    pixels = new int[width * height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);        
    getActualBitmap();
}

public ArrayList<Point> getPoints(){
    return points;
}

public void getActualBitmap() {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x+=2) {
        int firstY = -1, lastY = -1;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y+=2) {
            boolean transparent = (pixels[y * width + x] == Color.TRANSPARENT);
            if (!transparent) {
                if (firstY == -1) {
                    firstY = y;
                }
                lastY = y;
            }
        }
        if (firstY != -1) {
            points.add(new Point(x, firstY));
            points.add(new Point(x, lastY));
        }
    }
}
```

}

2) MyShapre.java

```
class MyShape{
    CustomShape customShape ;
    Point points[];
    private int x, y;
    Path path = new Path();
    public MyShape(Context context) {           
        customShape = new CustomShape(ScaleTestActivity.this);
        points = new Point[customShape.getPoints().size()];
        for(int i=0;i<customShape.getPoints().size();i++){
            points[i] = new Point();
            points[i] = customShape.getPoints().get(i); 
        }
    }
    public Path getPath(){
        return path;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(int i =0 ;i<points.length;i++){             
            Point point = new Point(points[i].x + getX(), points[i].y + getY());
            path.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            canvas.drawPoint(point.x,point.y,paint);
        }
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }       
}
```

}

3) MainPanel.java

```
    class MainPanel extends View{
        Context context;
        MyShape myShape;
        boolean flag = false;
        public MainPanel(Context context) {         
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            myShape = new MyShape(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            myShape.onDraw(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            int x,y;
            x = (int)event.getX();
            y = (int)event.getY();
            Point point = new Point(x, y);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                myShape.setX(x);
                myShape.setY(y);
                RectF rectF = new RectF();
                Path path = myShape.getPath();
                path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
                Region region = new Region();

                region.setPath(path, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));

                if(region.contains(x,y)){
                    flag = true;
                    Log.i("System out","onDown");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:               
                Log.i("System out","onMove : "+flag);
                if(flag){
                    myShape.setX(x);
                    myShape.setY(y);
                    Log.i("System out","onMove");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//              myShape.setX(x);
//              myShape.setY(y);
                flag = false;
                Log.i("System out","onUp");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

4) ScaleTestActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(new MainPanel(this));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a Polygon class to detect touches on rotated bitmaps. It's based mostly on information and code from this site http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/. This should work with your code.

```
public class Polygon {

// Polygon coodinates.
private final int[] polyY, polyX;

// Number of sides in the polygon.
private final int polySides;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 * @param px Polygon y coods.
 * @param py Polygon x coods.
 * @param ps Polygon sides count.
 */
public Polygon( final int[] px, final int[] py, final int ps ) {
    polyX = px;
    polyY = py;
    polySides = ps;
}

/**
 * Checks if the Polygon contains a point.
 * @see "http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/"
 * @param x Point horizontal pos.
 * @param y Point vertical pos.
 * @return Point is in Poly flag.
 */
public boolean contains( final float x, final float y ) {

    boolean oddTransitions = false;
    for( int i = 0, j = polySides -1; i < polySides; j = i++ ) {
        if( ( polyY[ i ] < y && polyY[ j ] >= y ) || ( polyY[ j ] < y && polyY[ i ] >= y ) ) {
            if( polyX[ i ] + ( y - polyY[ i ] ) / ( polyY[ j ] - polyY[ i ] ) * ( polyX[ j ] - polyX[ i ] ) < x ) {
                oddTransitions = !oddTransitions;          
            }
        }
    }
    return oddTransitions;
}


}
```

You could add this constructor to help you convert a Point array to a Polygon object.

```
public Polygon(Point[] points){
    polySides = points.length;
    polyY = new int[polySides];
    polyX = new int[polySides];

    for(int i = 0; i < polySides; i++){
        polyY[i] = points[i].y;
        polyX[i] = points[i].x;
    }
}
```

You might be able to use it in your MyShape class with this method.

```
 public boolean isTouched(final float X, final float Y){
   final Polygon p = new Polygon(points);
      return p.contains(X, Y);
}
```

Now if you have an odd shape you should be able to detect exactly if the use touches it. I have used this method many times.

Comment: thanks for replying.it works for me by doing some of the modification. i am able to draw points array on canvas and map the touch event on it when move.thanks once again dude.

Comment: @theJosh can you help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276192/how-to-find-custom-shape-speicific-area

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a way to tell whether a touch event falls on the non-transparent portion of your drawn bitmap?  If so, why don't you just map the touch coordinate to the proper pixel on the bitmap and test the color?

And if that's the case, then you can skip all the path clipping stuff, since the link you posted was only doing that to overcome emulator inefficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated so I am not going to provide the full source but I will give you an idea.

You need to transfer your shape in to a triangles collection, then on touch find the nearest point of your shape and check if your are inside this point triangle.

For searching and sorting points you can use [red-black-red tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) structure.

The search algorithm eventually should be at O(log(N)) and creating shape structure should be O(N*Log(N))