# How to find custom shape speicific area?

Tags: graphics, graph, geometry, computational-geometry, java-2d

**please , see following image, here you can see blue rectangle is custom shape bounds and custom shape is shoe , i want to find area of a portion written in image and i want that area in form of rectangle**

do is there any path iterator concept ?

### Note

custom shape i derived from image of the same size.

[image]

Comment: What are the restrictions?  Prefer width over height??

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes Prefer width and the target area must be within the shoe shape bounds for example within the blue rectangle.

Comment: @MadProgrammer any updates yet ?

Comment: is your image vector or photo (not sharp edges) ? also do you know the bounding box size and position ?

Comment: photo but having some sharp images as shown in the picture, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1.create table for all bounding box-rect perimeter lines

- each value in it will represent the empty space length form border line to shape
- something like this:

[image: shape perimeter space]

- the values are found by simple image scanning until first non space color found

2.now bruteforce find the biggest rectangle area

```
x,y = top left corner
 for  xs = 1 to bounding box width
  now scan the max valid height of rectangle from x to x + xs (x grows to the right)
  // it should be the min y0[x..x+xs]
   remember the biggest valid area/size combination
```

- do this for all 4 combinations (star from the other corners)

I now Brute-force is slow but

- you can divide perimeter lines not by pixels but with some step instead
- also I am sure this can be optimized somehow
- for example by derivation of perimeter find the extremes and check from them backwards
- when the size will start shrinking then stop ...
- of course take in mind that on complicated shapes this optimization will not work ...